# getting festival to talk at start up ubuntu 14.04

Tags: scripts

using this script:

```
week=$(date +”%A” )
day=$(date +”%e” )
echo hello $USER you are super awesome i am your processor | festival –tts
echo today is $week $day | festival –tts
echo have a nice day | festival –tts
```

But it is not working thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm not a script guy (yet), but you are piping the output of your echo command into the next command, and I'm not sure that this is what you want.  Try  `week=$(date +”%A” ) day=$(date +”%e” ) && echo hello $USER you are super awesome i am your processor | festival –tts && echo today is $week $day | festival –tts && echo have a nice day | festival –tts`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just a matter of forum formatting but the festival program's `tts` option needs a double hyphen i.e. `echo have a nice day | festival --tts`. Regardless it would be helpful if you mentioned __how__ it fails - including any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

More simple that you can imagine.
From `man festival`

**--** tts   Synthesize text in files as speech no files means read from stdin (implies no interaction by default)

So `--tts` and not `-tts`
Some option is Linux are with 2 `-`, usually are the less used with long names, some alias to help human to remember a short option (e.g. `gzip --best` acts as `gzip -9` to select the best compression level).

You have to modify each call to festival putting `--tts` instead of `-tts` e.g.:

```
echo have a nice day | festival --tts
```

Version:
festival: Festival Speech Synthesis System: 2.1:release November 2010.

Notes:

- for some reasons in your post there is the symbol `–` and not the standard minus `-`. You have to use the minus to specify the option.
- Older version of Festival (<=1.4) didn't seems to support the redirection from `echo` [Bug688940](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-accessibility-bugs/2011-January/002667.html). 
  If you have an old version you can follow the syntax of the relative version, [you can check if is ok this link](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/manual/), or you can update your version with `apt-get`.
  `apt-get update && upt-get install festival`

Excerpt from the Bug

> This is an error due to incorrect syntax for festival. **Festival does not
>   use the echo and redirects to speak**. Correct syntax is documented in the
>   manual, available at http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/manual/

Comment: What does SIOD ERROR: unbound variable : echo

Comment: On my system give no error. I'm updating the reference to the system. Which version do you have?